# Using node-schedule to schedule at 0th and 30th minute

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm trying to come-up with a cron expression (using [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule)) which will help me schedule a function on the 0th and 30th minute of the hour. Whatever time we start the app, it must run at the 0th minute and 30th minute of the hour.

This would work but i don't think the rule regarding 0th and 30th minute would work!

```
schedule.scheduleJob('* */30 * * * *', runFunc);
```

Below recurrence rule would run every hour at 30 minutes after the hour, but is it possible to change this to include even 0th minute?

```
var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.minute = 30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just remove the wildcard for seconds expression otherwise you get function calls every second during the minute is at 0th and 30th minutes. Rest of the code should be fine. (#)

Thus this should work:

```js
schedule.scheduleJob('0 */30 * * * *', () => console.log(new Date()));
```

Here is the debug code for your reference (checking input at 0th and 30th seconds)

```js
var schedule = require('node-schedule')
schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', () => console.log("now at " + new Date()));
schedule.scheduleJob('*/30 * * * * *', () => console.log(new Date()));
```

(#) *I edited my answer that was previously `0,*/30` however noticed that you just need `*/30` to get 0th and 30th minutes calls.*